# XSLT format a xml data file to multiple table display using HTML format

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, w3c

I have a xml format data file, it contains information about tests, I want to get a good look view in browser, I want exact these information in different tables, all test info table, every module test info table, and test failed case table.

```
<testsuites tests="111" failures="3" disabled="0" errors="0" time="60.947" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="ChdrvTestAout" tests="4" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="ChdrvTestTuner" tests="28" failures="3" disabled="0" errors="0" time="60.944">
    <testcase name="Case0001" status="run" time="0.001" classname="ChdrvTestTuner" />
    <testcase name="Case0007" status="run" time="27.271" classname="ChdrvTestTuner">
      <failure message="Value of: CHDRV_TEST_TUNER_0007()&#x0A;  Actual: 0&#x0A;Expected: (1)&#x0A;Which is: 1" type=""><![CDATA[src/chdrv_tuner_test.cc:71
Value of: CHDRV_TEST_TUNER_0007()
  Actual: 0
Expected: (1)
Which is: 1]]></failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="FactorialTest" tests="3" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="IsPrimeTest" tests="3" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I want to using XSLT format to HTML, to show data in multiple tables, I want to show this data in seperate module tables, like format:

```
-------------------------------------
module name  |  tests    |     failures
---------------------------------------
alltests     |   111     |      3
--------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
module name  |  tests    |     failures
---------------------------------------
ChdrvTestAout|   4       |      0
--------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
module name   |  tests    |     failures
---------------------------------------
ChdrvTestTuner|   28      |      3
--------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
casename  |   module             |      failed message
----------------------------------------------------------------------
case0007  |   ChdrvTestTuner     | src/chdrv_tuner_test.cc:71
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

please see what I have tried here http://www.pastebin.ca/2414163, 
but it only show the "alltest" table of the first one above?
how to write XSLT to do this?  highly appreciate your help

Here is the "/" template of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2 align="center">ChangHong driver test report!!!</h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testsuites"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testsuite"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testcase"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="failure"/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

many thanks!!!

Comment: I tried using some xsl:templates like,
`<xsl:apply-templates select="testsuites"/> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testsuite"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testcase"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="failure"/>` it only show the first templates format. I don't know why it only show the first table about "alltest" above. 
do you want to see what I tried? but I don't know how to show you?

Comment: @LarsH please see what I have tried, http://www.pastebin.ca/2414163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this stylesheet is executed, it starts by applying templates to the root node, `/`. This fires your `xsl:template  match="/"`.

While that template is being applied, the context node is `/`. So when it processes

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testsuites"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testsuite"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testcase"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="failure"/>
```

each of those XPath expressions is evaluated relative to `/`. So for the first one, you're asking it to apply templates to `/testsuites` (immediate child[ren] of the root node named `testsuites`). That's fine, because there is such a node.

But for the second one, you're asking it to apply templates to `/testsuite` (immediate children of the root node, named `testsuite`). No such node exists. The same is true for `testcase` and `failure`.

It doesn't matter that you have templates that match those other elements, because you are never applying templates to them.

To fix the problem, apply templates using the descendant axis:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="testsuites"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//testsuite"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//testcase"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//failure"/>
```

By the way, in your match patterns such as

```
<xsl:template match="//testsuite">
```

the `//` doesn't accomplish anything. A match pattern can match any node anywhere in the document; it's as if it's an XPath expression for which the context node is arbitrary. What *does* matter is that the matched node has been selected by an `xsl:apply-templates` somewhere else.

Another way to say all that is that the `apply-templates select` expressions need to be explicit about context, while `match` patterns do not. So you need to move the `//` from the `match` patterns to the `apply-templates` select expressions.